# Better text for the Enlightened Badge

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, enlightened-badge, badge-description

I just learned that the Enlightened badge, is for the First (in time order) answer on a question that is also accepted (with 10 upvotes).

Up until now I thought it was for the First answer for a user that got accepted (with 10 upvotes).

The current text is

> First answer was accepted with at least 10 up votes

I'm suggesting:

> The First answer for a question was accepted with at least 10 upvotes

though other suggestions would be fine.

Comment: How about: "First to answer and accepted with at least 10 upvotes"  (P.S. isn't it "enlightened"?)

Comment: @Aaronaught, yep, I've fixed it, post your comment as an answer and I'll upvote that, I like it better than mine

Comment: "The first answer to a question was accepted, and received at least 10 upvotes" -- even less ambiguous, but getting wordy.

Comment: @Aether, That's a better one also, but I think I prefer Aaronaught's.  p.s. Do you get a notification for this when I use a separate A & E?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I don't visit Meta all that often. ;)

Comment: Yes, yes, yes.  Ever since I started using SO (nine months ago), I thought it was awarded the first time any one of your answers became both accepted and 10-upvoted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per my comment, my suggestion for the text is:

> First to answer and accepted with at least 10 upvotes.

Not too verbose, but still pretty clear IMUEO<sup>*</sup>.

<sub>* In My Un-Enlightened Opinion</sub>

Comment: This will be the text starting with the next build.

Comment: Too bad you didn't get the enlightened badge for this

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

> "Gave the first answer to a question, and that answer received at least 10 upvotes and was accepted"

(Aaronaught's comment is great, but is still IMOPO* ambiguous, since a single user can give multiple answers to a question).

<sup>* In my overly pedantic opinion</sup>

Comment: I wonder why it has to be the first given answer, and I'm thinking maybe you were looking for something like: 'Gave an accepted answer with 10 upvotes prior to editing,' or, 'Gave an accepted answer with 10 upvotes in the first $timeperiod.'?  Maybe the latter of the two would be best because the sooner would discourage necessary edition.