# What does "First answer was accepted with score of 10 or more" mean?

Tags: discussion, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better text for the Enlightened Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37857/better-text-for-the-enlightened-badge)

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969694/what-is-the-outcome-in-javascript-with-multiple-librarys-that-use/5969712#5969712) was accepted with a score of 11, but I did not get the badge, why is that?

Comment: @Jeff, why is this an `exact duplicate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it some time. The badge scripts run at various intervals.

There is a 2 minute and 44 second difference between [when you were awarded the Nice Answer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=561731) (i.e. when the badge script ran) and [when your answer was accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5969694/timeline), so you will probably get the badge on the next run. I don't know how often they run, though.

Comment: hmmm ok. i got the `Good Answer` badge pretty quickly

Comment: @Neal: Actually, that badge is "Nice Answer" (10).  At this rate you'll have to wait another twenty minutes for "Good Answer" (25).

Comment: @Rick, whatever it was, i got it pretty quick :-p

Comment: still nothing...

Comment: w00t, i just got it :-)